# Steam not opening or responding

Tags: drivers, games, steam

I deleted steam and re-downloaded. After I accepted the Terms and Conditions nothing happened. I tried opening it from the Terminal instead and this was the output:

```
steam steam://open/games
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r300_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r300
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this problem a long time ago, but now I forgot solution :) Steam for Ubuntu is 32-bit, maybe you need lib32.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

and install Steam from the terminal, not from the Ubuntu Software Center maybe.

Answer (score 0):

**I found solution for you.**

Type this:

```
 cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu 
 mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
 cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Steam bundles old libs and are colliding with mesa drivers, that is also why closed drivers aren't seeing this problem.
Good look. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 15.10 64 bit, fine...
Please, show us your hardwares installed.
Are you using Graphic card from Nvidia ? (if yes Which one are you using? )

From where are you installing the steam client ? 
Are you installing from the package download on steam website (http://store.steampowered.com/about/ ) or from ubuntu software center ?